# Autoadjust chracters within specific string length

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string in form of:
    1  name          25          11          45          66

I need to replace  11 with -55.88 and 45 with 99.67
But i dont want to break the sequcence of spaces.

Present string:

```
1  name          25          11          45          66
```

Expected result:

```
1  name          25         -55.88    99.67     66
```

white Spaces count  between 25 to 11 and 11 to 45 and 45 to 66 is equal to 10.

At present when i split and replace value with another value the sequece of space shifted towards left for example

```
1  name         25         -55.88          99.67          66
```

Comment: I'm struggling with "sequence of spaces." I can't see the difference in spaces between before and after. Replacing 11 with -55.88 doesn't change the spaces. Maybe you could format the numbers as code so that we get a fixed-width font. Maybe you're even typing more spaces but we can't see them.

Comment: Replace the chars, then Format with padding. i.e., [String.PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft), [String.PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright).

Comment: See also [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). If you're using this method to align chars in WinForms, you need to use a monospaced font or use a dedicated control, as the ListView or the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the target repeatedly using [`string.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputString = "1  name          25          11          45          66";
    string replacedString = inputString.Replace("11", "-55.88").Replace("45", "99.67");

    Console.WriteLine(replacedString);
}
```

Outputting:

```
1  name          25          -55.88          99.67          66
```