# string replace with empty characters

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string of empty spaces with a max length of 12

```
string EmptySpaces = "-          -";
```

need to replace with runtime characters inside these spaces without exceeding the max length.

For example:

```
string EmptySpaces = "-          -";
result = "-53        -"  or "-5         -" or "3          -"
```

I already tried string.format and string.replace but not getting any fruitful result.

```
string EmptySpaces = "-          -";
result = "-53        -"  or "-5         -" or "3          -"
```

Comment: Show the actual code you've tried please.

Comment: And what are "runtime characters"?

Comment: runtime character i mean to say not fixed length character.

Comment: What did you try? What did you get? What did you *want* to get? Please edit that into your question

Comment: string can be used like an array of char.

Comment: You've done a poor job of explaining what you're actually trying to accomplish. Please state your requirement more clearly and show us what you have tried.

Comment: [Already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174197/autoadjust-chracters-within-specific-string-length), you didn't take the hint. Learn how to **format** a string with padding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this with `Substring`:

```cs
int i = 111; 
string emptySpaces = "-          -";

if (i.ToString().Length <= 10)
    emptySpaces = "-" + i.ToString() + emptySpaces.Substring(i.ToString().Length + 1);
```

In your example you are keeping the '-' signs at the start and the end of your string, therefore I guess you don’t want numbers with a length of more than 10 characters.

The `Substring` function then replaces characters in your string starting after the first character. I have added a '-' character at the start of the string, and therefor also added a +1 to the `i.ToString().Length` part of the substring, since it looks like you want to keep the '-' signs.